# Tingling/shock when holding USB plug of externally-powered device (speakers, etc) and touching HDMI/DP plug

Tags: power-supply, power, displayport, electric-shock

**PC:**

- GPU: Gigabyte RTX 2070 Windforce
- CPU: i7 7700
- RAM: Kingston HyperX Fury 16GB DDR4
- Mobo: GIGABYTE GA-B250-FINTECH
- PSU: EVGA 750 G2
- Case: Coolermaster HAF 912 Combat

I'm troubleshooting an existing issue involving my Display Port monitor flickering when the USB plug of an externally-powered USB device (speakers, external HDD) touches the I/O port or USB port on my PC. The flickering continues to happen when touching the front case USB port, despite these being unplugged from the motherboard.

During testing I noticed that if I'm holding the USB plug of one of these devices and I touch a USB port or I/O plate, I get a sharp tingle/minor shock in that hand where contact is made.

I unplugged EVERYTHING from the PC except the PSU power cable. Still get the shock.
I unplugged the PSU power cable and plugged in the Display Port cable and still got the shock.
I tried it again, except this time touched the Display Port cable and then the HDMI cable directly while holding the USB cable, and still got a shock.

I'm pretty certain my apartment is grounded (got a Belkin power board with Grounding detection, and it's not telling me there's an issue), and the monitor flickering issues happened at a friend's house, too.

All investigation with the screen flickering pointed towards a case/PSU/motherboard issue. I changed the motherboard, put everything outside of the case, tried it with a different monitor, went to a friends house and tried a different PSU there, with the same flickering symptoms showing up.

The fact that there is shocking/tingling with the video cables themselves adds another crazy and weird variable to my situation.

**Is shocking/tingling in this specific instance normal?**

Comment: “Is shocking/tingling in this specific instance normal?” - No; It absolutely isn’t normal.  My immediate thought absolutely is a grounding issue.  Do you live in a region of the world where the power isn’t stable?

Comment: Nope, I live in New Zealand which is (as far as I understand) pretty stable! We also have 3-pin wall sockets, and I'm running a Belkin power board with grounding detection which is reporting no faults. I have also seen the monitor flickering issue when testing this computer at a friend's place, and in a computer store (albeit much more mildly at the store)

Comment: Well it isn’t normal and the monitor flickering is Electromagnetic Interference more than likely which would have to be pretty strong to effect any monitor produced in the last decade

Comment: Fair enough! I'm really confused by this issue. On the one hand I could see it being a case/PSU grounding issue with the flickering. 

However the fact that if I plug the DP cable into my primary screen and the HDMI cable into my second screen, then hold the USB plug and touch the PC-end of each cable (while totally unplugged from the PC) and get the prickly feeling... really complicates the troubleshooting!

Comment: It’s possible your just particularly sensitive, but even then, that doesn’t explain the flickering.  Do you have access to a UPS that will provide clean power?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your comment! I don't have a UPS unfortunately, but I'll get an electrician in to check the apartment grounding situation in a week or so once this COVID thing has settled down. Fingers crossed nothing breaks between now and then!

Comment: If you get a UPS, be sure you get one with a Sinewave output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the situation is dangerous. There is a crossover of significant voltages here (over 25 volts) . I suggest you test the USB plug / port with an AC voltmeter with one end connected to the apartment ground. Be certain of your apartment grounding . This is a safety issue. If your AC power cord from the computer is a two wire cord, see if there is a narrow plug blade and a broad plug blade, make sure that your outlet has broad and narrow slots.

With proper installation and grounding there should not be any tingling.  This is distinct from the odd static electricity spark when touching things.

You may need an electrician to test your apartment wiring and grounding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm pretty certain the apartment socket is grounded. We have 3-pin sockets in NZ, and it's impossible to plug them in the wrong way. I'm also running a Belkin power board with grounding indication which is showing no issues. Would you say this is a problem with the apartment rather than the equipment?

https://www.officemax.co.nz/Tools-Hardware/Power-Boards/Belkin-Surge-Protector-8-Outlet-2-USB-Ports-2695448?gs=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwte71BRBCEiwAU_V9h_zAfa0sm_1RgDlGomqsuzpcMeJxD2Ig6ycTqFdddefuaBnK0OciiBoCnXgQAvD_BwE

Comment: I measured from the groundside of my desktop computer to the USB metal part of the enclosure with a commercial voltmeter and got 1 volt AC which is about normal. I doubt it is an issue with your apartment but you need good equipment and measurement skills to be certain. Also as the landlord about your grounding at the apartment input.

Comment: Gotcha! The screen flickering happened at a friend's place too. I wonder if I'm dealing with two issues here - a problem within my PC, and a problem with my apartment.

I should mention that this isn't purely a USB port issue. My original post wasn't clear, but if I plug the DP cable into my primary screen and the HDMI cable into my second screen, then hold the USB plug in my hand and touch the PC-end of each cable (while the monitors are totally unplugged from the PC) I still get the prickly feeling

Comment: You need to check the grounding of the outlets you plug into.

Comment: I've got one of these bad boys which is showing no fault
https://www.bunnings.co.nz/deta-power-outlet-tester-plug_p0322372

Is that sufficient? If not, I'll get an electrician in

Comment: If you were not experiencing any tingling , the outlet tester should be ok, but then that would point to your computers. I would be inclined to check it professionally to give you a starting point,

Comment: Ran one further experiment. Took the monitor with DP cable and a wall-powered USB device into a different room, plugged them both into the wall and held the USB-A cable and touched the DP cable - still tingling.

Just so that I fully understand the situation: the power cables for the 2 USB devices I've been testing with are both 2-pin plugs as opposed to our more common 3-pin plugs.

Is tingling in this specific case abnormal given the lack of grounding pins on these USB devices, or is it the job of the grounding pin on the monitor's power plug to deal with this errant current?

Comment: "Is tingling in this specific case abnormal given the lack of grounding pins on these USB devices"   It could be if the AC plugs cannot differentiate between hot and ground. The equipment probably will expect to be connected with the correct polarity unless completely isolated inside which it obviously is not.

Comment: Sorry my electrical knowledge isn't quite up to par! What do you mean about the AC plugs differentiating between hot and ground? I'm also not sure what you mean about isolation.

I should mention that it's impossible to plug our devices in the wrong way around here:
https://mk0asherfergussgajut.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/australian-power-outlet-1.jpg

Comment: A regulation two wire device (as I noted above) has a broad blade and narrow blade and will only go into a regulation outlet. 3 wire plug with ground obviously only go in one way. What I mean by two wire device internal isolation is that the higher voltage wires are not connected to the outside case in any way, even if the outside case is metal. PC desktop manufacturers usually use 3 wire AC cables to ensure proper grounding. For sure in your case something is very wrong. Good circuits do not shock or tingle.

Comment: Ah, I'm getting it now. Just to clear up any misunderstanding, this isn't a case of me touching the casing of the USB device then getting shocked by the DP/HDMI cable, but rather me touching the USB device's plug and getting shocked by the DP/HDMI cable. It sounds as though this is likely still a home grounding issue?

Comment: You need an electrician to test your apartment grounding. I added that note for complete clarity to my answer above.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the advice, I appreciate you taking the time. Have a great weekend

Comment: You might mark my answer as helpful given all I have done for you

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to the Stack Exchange format! Done now